# I am having trouble applying Remote Validation to my Razor Page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, remote-validation

I have seen 4 or 5 different videos, two pages and 1 SO link talking about Remote Validation in Razor pages, but I am not getting a few things with these examples. For instance, in the examples, I have seen they are using a variation on a duplicate email checker. Its a simple example and I sort of understand what is going on but I have not been able to extrapolate that out into my project

In my site I have an ItemModel that contains a FromProperty, which is a location. I am trying to check what is entered into that box against a known list of locations. I have added this to my page.

```
public async Task<JsonResult> OnPostCheckLocation(string location)
{
    LocationModel ValidLocation = await LocationModel.CreateAsync(location);
    var check = ValidLocation.Location;
    var valid = !check.Equals("XXX");
    // "X" is just a placeholder for
    // an invalid location
    return new JsonResult(valid);
}
```

The ValidLocation will return "XXX" if the entered location doesn't match anything from the database. The next thing I need to do is add the Page Remote attribute, but it isn't clear to me where that goes. I have tried adding to the page model above the ItemModel property.

```
public ItemModel Item { get; set; } = new ItemModel();
```

I have tried putting above the FromLocation property in the ItemModel Class and neither one ever hit my OnPostCheckLocation method. I have also tried several other things but I was never able to get it working. This is the Remote Page attribute I used

```
[PageRemote(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Location",
HttpMethod = "post",
PageHandler = "CheckLocation")]
```

And lastly my _ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml does have jquery.validate and jquery.validate.unobtrusive included. So, can someone help me understand where the Remote Page attribute should go and let me know if there is something else that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> neither one ever hit my OnPostCheckLocation method.

You can use `F12` to see if any error messages in the console.You may meet 400 error.Because in your Remote Page attribute you miss `AdditionalFields` :    A comma separated list of additional fields that should be included in the validation request .The `AdditionalFields` property must include the request verification token because request verification takes place by default in Razor Pages. If this field is not included in a POST request, the request will fail with a 400 Bad Request status code.

Razor Pages remote validation requires the property to be validated must be a direct descendent of the PageModel class (i.e. not a property of a child property of the PageModel, also referred to as a "nested property")

Try to apply the PageRemote attribute to the location property  in the razor page, and set the page handler method in the current page:

```
    [PageRemote(
    ErrorMessage = "Invalid Location",
    AdditionalFields = "__RequestVerificationToken",
    HttpMethod = "post",
    PageHandler = "CheckLocation"
    )]
    [BindProperty]
    public string location { get; set; }
```

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it:

IndexModel.cshtml.cs

```
 public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
  
        [PageRemote(
    ErrorMessage = "Invalid Location",
    AdditionalFields = "__RequestVerificationToken",
    HttpMethod = "post",
    PageHandler = "CheckLocation"
    )]
        [BindProperty]
        public string location { get; set; }

        public async Task<JsonResult> OnPostCheckLocation(string location)
        {
           // LocationModel ValidLocation = await LocationModel.CreateAsync(location);
            var check = "XXX"; //do your staff,just for test
            var valid = !check.Equals("XXX");
            // "X" is just a placeholder for
            // an invalid location
            return new JsonResult(valid);
        }
    }
```

IndexModel.cshtml:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}


<form method="post">
    <input asp-for="location" />
    <span asp-validation-for="location"></span><br>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>



@section scripts{
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
   
}
```

result:

[image]